# is there such thing as Ruby gems for Grails?

Tags: grails

is there such a thing as groovy gems in Grails? I thought that Grails is easier and faster than ruby on rails and yet there  are a lot of things that are ready done in rails where I need to write code for it in grails.... like the goecoder service for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails has plugins, which are quite similar to ruby gems.  You can find a list of available plugins at http://www.grails.org/plugins/